# CSS: Overlapping DIVs issue

Tags: css, html

I want to have 2 divs. looking like that:

[image]

The problem is that if i just set `margin-top: -50px` DIV2 becomes on TOP. 
If i use z-index, DIV2 goes behind, but the form on DIV2 cannot be used, since it DIV2 is somewhat behind, cannot be clicked, selected or any of those.

How do I make it work?

DIV1 css:

```
position:relative;
height: 350px;
margin-top: -50px;
z-index: -10;
```

DIV2 css:

```
padding: 24px;
z-index: 10;
margin-bottom: -50px;
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a third, transparent div and give it the largest z-index. Than you place your form in this new div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing any details, it could be related to negative z-indexes.

The stacking order makes distinction between positive and negative values:

> The specs define 7 painting layers. Starting from back to front, they
>   are:
>
> ```
> The borders and background of the current stacking context
> Positioned descendants with negative z-index
> Nonpositioned block-level descendants with no z-index property defined -- paragraphs, tables, lists, and so on
> Floating descendants and their contents
> Nonpositioned inline content
> Positioned descendants with no z-index, z-index: auto, or z-index: 0
> Positioned descendants with z-index greater than 0
> ```
>
> Source is [here](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex).

Try making z-index on div1 positive instead of the z-index of div2 negative

Be careful, z-index only applies on the stack level of a box whose position value is one of absolute, fixed, or relative.

Comment: i corrected as you said, and instead of having 10 and -10 z-index, i made it 10 and 5, but the layout broke ;\

Comment: Be careful, z-index only applies on the stack level of a box whose position value is one of absolute, fixed, or relative.

Comment: Yes, that was a problem i didn't realize.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to the Wesley's help, here is the actual Code:

DIV1 css:

```
position:relative;
z-index: 100;
```

DIV2 css:

```
z-index: 10;
margin-bottom: -50px;
```