# Target multiple overlapped divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 4 divs overlapped like a cover flow, a [**FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/47S55/)

I have managed to stack them in the right way (one over another) but I know I'm doing something wrong with z-index. 
3 Problems I have:

1. I can only target the first div (#product-image), all other 3 divs are not responding to click events.
2. Tried to toggle the perspective view in a smooth transition but obviously I'm doing it wrong too.
3. The whole cover flow is not centered although I have specified wrapper width and set margin:0 auto.

I've tried to follow **this SO answer [CSS: Overlapping DIVs issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896507/css-overlapping-divs-issue)**
But I can only make it work as much as 3 divs, not in my case.

Structure below:
HTML

```
<div class="product-download">
    <div id="product-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x216" />
    </div>
    <div id="in-situ-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x216" />
    </div>
    <div id="product-flyer">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x216" />
    </div>
    <div id="data-sheet">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x216" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.product-download {
    position:relative;
    width:934px;
    height:397px;
}
.product-download > div {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
}
#product-image {
    z-index:6;
}
#in-situ-image {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    z-index:5;
    left:120px;
}
#product-flyer {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    z-index:4;
    left:265px;
}
#data-sheet {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-30deg) translateZ(-100px);
    z-index:3;
    left:410px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(".product-download div").click(function () {
    alert(this.id);
    $(this).fadeTo('slow').css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective( 0px ) rotateY( 0deg ) translateZ(0px)');
    $(this).prevAll().fadeTo('slow').css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 30deg ) translateZ(-100px)');
    $(this).nextAll().fadeTo('slow').css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg ) translateZ(-100px)');
});
```

Comment: I'm sure it's not the problem of `z-index`, in fact you can still see the other divs, it's the problem of `translateZ()`, not sure how to solve this.

Comment: I had a little mess around with this and I can't seem to find a fix. It is indeed translateZ() that is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys it seems to be a problem of translateZ(), tried remove that and I can click through, but the output is not ideal then.

Comment: @Godinall Ok I think I got it working, take a look at my answer.

Comment: @KingKing Just dropping you a comment in case you would like to know a possible solution to this. Take a look at my answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said I have been messing with it a bit to see what I can get working. I have found a way to make them clickable! You will need sort out the `z-index` as well tho but this does get it working.

Setting the `transform` on the parent seems to allow the others to be clicked again. I'm not 100% sure how that works to be honest but it does fix the problem.

**CSS:**

```
.product-download {
    position:relative;
    width:934px;
    height:397px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/47S55/4/)

**Note:** If people could check this that would be great. It seemed to stop working for me but then started working again... Not sure if I miss clicked or something. Please leave a comment stating if this solved the problem for you.

---

And just an example for the `z-index`, you will need to change that too or they will go through each other.

Just added:

```
.css('z-index','1');
```

To the end of `prevAll()` and `nextAll()`.

And then on `fadeTo()` set:

```
.css('z-index','9999');
```

This is just a quick example, you can neaten it up a little. Hope this helps!

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/47S55/6/)

---

Fixed the `z-index` problem.

**jQuery:**

```
$(this).nextAll().each(function (index) {
    $(this).fadeTo('slow').css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -30deg ) translateZ(-100px)').css('z-index', '-' + index);
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/47S55/9/)

Comment: Thank you @Ruddy, this solve one major problem. Small issue, when you click on other layers other than first one, the z-index are not right, which I think I can fix. Your answer didn't solve my other 2 problems though if you don't mind having a look too.

Comment: @Godinall I knew you would say that! I just updated, enjoy! :D

Comment: thank you VV much, but still small bugs, when you click all of them and the z-index get messed again...sorry

Comment: @Godinall Oh yes of course it would, silly me. I will fix that in a moment.

Comment: I don't care about the `z-index` problem of the OP, this solution just solves the hardest thing related to `translateZ`, I could not believe how strange the transformed layout works that way. Although I've done some transforms just to enjoy the visual effect, not cared  about ***interaction***, many 3d models using CSS3 out there also support ***interaction***, but not really cared about them, just thought it's simple.

Comment: looks like the odd behavior is because of using `perspective` **separately** for the each `transform` in each `div`. If you remove all the `perspective()` in each div and just use `perspective: 600px` on the `.product-download`, it will work expectedly.

Comment: @Godinall Take a look at the edit, let me know if it glitches at all.

Comment: @Ruddy, perfect, thank you! I'm sure I can solve the rest 2 problem myself.

Comment: @Godinall No problem, also you looking for something like this? [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/47S55/10/) - The animation does make it look a bit glitchy tho.

Comment: @Ruddy not sure if you are around, just found that this doesn't work properly in firefox, would you mind take another look for me?

Comment: @Godinall I will take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 problems: one with the z-index property and one with the translateZ property

To solve the z-index problem, you can try this code:

```
$(".product-download div").click(function() {
    // Get the maximum number of items and set the max z-index and the min z-index
    var max_zindex = $(".product-download div").length;
    var min_zindex = 1;
    // Get the item index    
    var index = $(".product-download div").index(this);
    // Fix the z-index position of all the divs
    $(this).css('z-index', max_zindex);
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".product-download div:not('" + id + "')").css('z-index', min_zindex);
});
```

The main problem is in the translateZ property.

Comment: This is not the cause, problem is translateZ()

Comment: I checked the code under Chrome. Now I see the problem :)
He has just one problem and it's related to the z-index property. I'm gonna edit the code